# Python- Compute the sum of numerical characters of every string in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have a dataframe with a column "dname".
It contains many rows of 2LD domain names. i.e. `[123ask , example92 , what3ver]`.

I want to find the number of digits for every string in every row.

So, to create a new column in the dataframe with values i.e. `[3 , 2 , 1]`.

I have:

```
df['numeric']= sum (x.isdigit() for b in df['dname'] for x in b)
```

And all i get is `6 6 6`
instead of `3 2 1`

Any help ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are summing `3 2 1`

Comment: added 'pandas' tag because poster is using the python pandas package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
df = {'dname':["123ask", "example92" , "what3ver"]}
df['numeric'] = [sum (x.isdigit()  for x in b) for b in df['dname']]
print(df['numeric'])
#>>> [3, 2, 1]
print(sum(df['numeric']))
#>>> 6
```

Comment: how to find the sum of digits?

Answer (score 0):

```
    df['numeric']= df['dname'].apply(lambda v : sum(x.isdigit() for x in v))
```

This would apply the desired operation to all the rows and is considerably faster

Comment: This gives `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'`

Comment: df['dname'] should be a series, not a list

Comment: how to find the sum of digits?